# XML and ServerXMLHTTP problem

Tags: xml, vb.net, post, serverxmlhttp

```
Error Type:
msxml3.dll (0x80072F0C)
A certificate is required to complete client authentication
```

I am sending an XML file to a remote server

```
putUrl =https://www.myweb.com/test/drhandler.php
xml_put = "<?xml version=""1.0""?><subscription id=""" & "14" &"""><status>" &"das" & "</status></subscription>"

Public Function SendBatch(xml_put,putUrl)
   Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML3.ServerXMLHTTP")
   xmlhttp.Open "PUT", putUrl , False
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   xmlhttp.send(xml_put)

   Set xmlhttp = Nothing
end function
```

Any help out there?

Comment: @ZAfrican.. you have asked numerous questions and not accepted any answers. You really should accept the best possible answer to your question whether it solves your problem at hand or not. otherwise you will be hard pressed to find someone willing to waste time answering your questions if you cannot take .2 seconds and acknowledge the effort. just sayin...

Comment: Sorry
I am new in this forum but i will go accept some answers
thanks for the advice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The server requires a client certificate. This certificate must be added to your machine or to the browser. The administrator of the server will have all the details for you.

Also: see **[this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/302080)**

Comment: Well, I am running in my local machine and posting  the data to a server. Dos it require the Certificate?

Comment: You need to ask the administrator of the server. I have no way of knowing this. The exception you are generating seems to indicate that a certificate is required. also see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/302080

Comment: do you mean administrator of the server where i am trying to send the data to? meaning https://www.myweb.com/test/drhandler.php

Comment: OK. However , how do i get the client certificate in order to Install it?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to say to me?

Comment: The Microsoft knowledgebase hyperlink in your answer no longer works. This is the updated link - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302080